# Response time between postman and alamofire

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire, postman

I'm currently working on a Swift 3 App and i am sadly surprised by the response time in the app...

By postman, my request is responding in 200ms but in the app, it feels like it's taking more than 10sec between the roquets and the response...

Here is a example of a request taking too much time :

```
class func getFriendPage(page : Int, callback : @escaping (Bool, JSON) -> Void) {
    let url = NetworkManager.getUrl() + "api/v1/challenges/friends?page=" + String(page)
    let params = [:] as [String : Any]?

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: NetworkManager.getHeader()).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

        if response.response != nil && (response.response?.statusCode)! < 300 {

            print("Status Code : \(response.response?.statusCode)")
            print("response : \(response.response)")
            print("result : \(response.result)")
            print("value : \(response.result.value)")

            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
            callback(true, json)
        } else {
            callback(false, JSON.null)
        }
    }
}
```

If someone can help me, it would be awesome! :D thanks a lot !
If you need more details, i'm still there !

Edit : I tried on postman on my mac with the personal hotspot of my phone : response time around 1.5 sec, cannot find where i lose those 9 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok my bad... don't use JSONEncoding.default if you have no parameters.. use URLEncoding.default...

Here an example :

```
class func getFriendPage(page : Int, callback : @escaping (Bool, JSON) -> Void) {
    let url = NetworkManager.getUrl() + "api/v1/challenges/friends?page=" + String(page)

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: [:], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: NetworkManager.getHeader()).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        if response.response != nil && (response.response?.statusCode)! < 300 {

            print("Status Code : \(response.response?.statusCode)")
            print("response : \(response.response)")
            print("result : \(response.result)")
            print("value : \(response.result.value)")

            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
            callback(true, json)
        } else {
            callback(false, JSON.null)
        }
    }
}
```